# How to create a save option ? to save change that is made in .txt file from python

Tags: python

this is my assignment:
Description: We are interested to develop a Costumer Management System for a company, which stores customers and orders information and helps system user to search, edit, and enter data. Each customer has a `CustomerNumber` (ID), `Name`, `Address`, and `Phone` which can be stored in a list such as `[1, “Amin Milani Fard”, “Columbia College”, 778]`. Each order has an `OrderNumber`, `CostumerNumber`, `OrderDate`, and `OrderedItemsList` such as `[5,1,”20/06/2011”, [“XYZ”, “ABC”, “LMNOP”]]`.

You will be given two input text files, customer.txt containing list of costumers, and orders.txt containing list of orders. First you need to read the input file and then based on the user choice apply a search, edit, add, or remove on customer and/or order list. Your program should repeat showing a menu as the following while the user did not entered 9 to quit:

```
**** Welcome to My Customer Management System ****
Please select an option
1.  Load the input files
2.  Search a customer
3.  Search an order
4.  Add a new customer
5.  Add a new order
6.  Delete a customer
7.  Delete an order
8.  Save data in files 
9.  Quit
```

im having problem with save data in files, i just dont get it this part. I thought when u make changes in option 4 ,5,6,7 it will automatically save. Is there anyway to save a txt file from python?

Comment: There are many ways to save a txt file from python. Show us what you've tried, and we can tell give you suggestions from there. Be sure to indent your code by four spaces for proper formatting.

Comment: k... im assuming is the f.close section... im working on it .. thx..,. be right back

Answer (score 0):

Go read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on file I/O, it's really good. Good luck solving that assignment of yours.

Comment: ok... im assuming is the f.close section... im working on it .. thx..,. be right back

Comment: A piece of friendly advice, Yuvin: Read the *entire* tutorial before you ask another question here. People on Stack Overflow are very friendly, but most of them don't enjoy answering questions that are already answered in the beginner's tutorial. Of course, you can ask if there's something specific you don't understand in the tutorial. Just show that you've made an effort yourself.